# .Net Regex for mm-dd-yy and others + yyymmdd

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I feel like I am chasing my tail.

I am trying to arrive at a .Net regex that will match on the following:

> mm-dd-yy  
>   m-dd-yy 
>   mm-d-yy 
>   m-d-yy

and (no dashes)

> yyyymmdd

Comment: Do you need leap years and proper days in a month? That will be a long RegEx if so :)
Or is it only for matching?

Comment: Does it need to be a regex? Can you use DateTime.Parse?

Comment: I find this useful when building regex http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: is the final result you are looking for to be DateTime object?

Comment: Note: if in fact you are looking for valid DateTime, none of the regular expressions will provide you with complete validation, like leap year, months with less than 31 days, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One or two digits followed by a dash, followed by one or two digits, followed by a dash, follows by to digits **or** eight digits:

```
(\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{2})|(\d{8})
```

Answer (score 1):

A very simple RegEx that just matches to the digits being in the correct places and matches all your formats:

```
^[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{2}$|^[0-9]{8}$
```

This does not validate those dates as actual possible dates, to do this you would be better off using DateTime.TryParse

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use Regex, or do you just care that it is a valid date?

```
    DateTime result;
    if(DateTime.TryParse(input, out result))
    {
        // you have your date in result
    }
```

Comment: this will only work if the string is in the current culture DateTime format

Answer (score 0):

Well it all comes down to how strict you want the matching to be.

```
[0-9]+\-[0-9]+\-[0-9]+
```

will match all the four top ones. But you can enter "99-99-99".

You can be a bit more strict with:

```
([0-1][0-2]|[0-9])\-(3[0-1]|[0-2]?[0-9]+)\-[0-9]{1,2}
```

This will only match dates where each component is in a valid range, but only to an extent. It would still match a February with 31 days (which it won't have in the Gregorian calendar). Also it will match `13-04-18` from 3 and onwards. You can use anchors to make it match the whole text (add `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end of the regex), but then it won't be able to find the dates inside a text.

You can add a precondition to make sure there's no weird digits around it though. Negative look-behind and negative look-ahead.

```
(?<![0-9])([0-1][0-2]|[0-9])\-(3[0-1]|[0-2]?[0-9]+)\-[0-9]{1,2}(?![0-9])
```

And so forth, but this regex has already become a proper behemoth. I would go with the second or third version and use `DateTime.Parse` to validate it.

There's only so far you can go with regex for dates before they become write-once and insane :) (what about leap years for example, etc. etc.)